# How to coalesce different collections?

Tags: rust

Say I have a function

```
fn process_graph_nodes(graph: Graph, nodes: Option<impl Iterator<Item=Node>){
    for node in nodes.unwrap_or_else(|| graph.all_nodes()) {
      //processing node
    }
}
```

where method `all_nodes` returns some type that implements `Iterator<Item=Node>`.
So, both `nodes.unwrap()` and `graph.all_nodes()` return iterators that yield `Node` type, but they are different types, what causes compilation error.

Is there any way to make that code compile, may be by turning both types into trait objects of `Iterator<Item=Node>`?

Comment: It would be good to add the error you get from the compiler to this question.

Comment: I don't think you can if you want static dispatch, do two `for` loop in a `if let Some` for the first one and the other one in the else condition.

Comment: I found a simple solution to define an

`enum EitherIter<L, R> {Left(L),Right(R),}`

and then implement `Iterator` for it, so i can combine iterators of different types that produce values of same type

Comment: Even better, `Itertools` crate already has such enum `Either`, that implements `Iterator` if both branches implement `Iterator` with same value type

Comment: that add a avoidable overheat

Comment: Please note, that the `Either` type comes not from `Itertools` itself, but from the [either crate](https://crates.io/crates/either)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would define an inner function and dispatch manually:

```
fn process_graph_nodes(graph: Graph, nodes: Option<impl Iterator<Item=Node>){
    fn process_internal(graph: Graph, nodes: impl Iterator<Item=Node>) {
        for node in nodes {
          //processing node
        }
    }
    match nodes {
        None => process_internal(graph, graph.all_nodes()),
        Some(n) => process_internal(graph, n),
    }
}
```

(I do not have a compiler at hand, but I think you can get the idea.)

This way, you avoid the potential costs of using `Either`.